# No internetwhen installing Kubuntu 14.04.5

Tags: internet

I have a new HP Pavilion laptop, and I'm trying to install Kubuntu 14.04.5 from a memory stick.  The installation starts correctly but my *hardwired* internet connection does not work. (Wireless does not work either.)  I get the X opposite "is connected to the Internet" at the beginning of the process. However, this is a dual-boot setup and the Internet connection works just fine for Windows 10.

To add to the enigma, I think but I'm not sure that I tried this earlier and the internet connection did work.  I have no idea what's changed, if anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just FYI, 14.04.5 will be end of life this month.

Comment: I thought that was a year from now, in 2019.

Comment: Sorry it is 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I considered changing to Kubuntu, as there are very good KDE software tools, which would leave my Ubuntu with tons of redundant dependencies. But always had those problems with the network manager, which would never go away. So I finally came back to Ubuntu. Some time later I tried out Kubuntu with Virtual Box, just for fun, and everything was fine. So I would recommend, if possible, choose an newer version.

Comment: That's an interesting observation.  I really do want to run native Kubuntu, but to diagnose the problem I should download and try to install Ubuntu.  If my problem somehow relates to differences between Ubuntu and Kubuntu, that would be very useful to know.

Comment: The issue just got a lot more puzzling.  I just tried out Ubuntu 16.04 from a memory stick.   I was able to get a wireless connection, but still no wired connection.  To summarize:

Comment: Kubuntu 14.04.5: neither wired nor wireless works; Ubuntu 16.04: wireless works, wired does not.

Comment: Wireless in Kubuntu   16.04 works, but wired does not.  Very puzzling.  I suspect the HP drivers, but I don't know what they are, and in any event installing them when I don't have a net connection at all (under 14.04.5) would be quite difficult.

Comment: Wireless works in later versions of Kubuntu; wireless still does not.

Comment: Paul, when working with wired connection, try out to disable wireless from the menu, and vice versa (if possible, if not just disconnect cable). Once there was a bug about that. Oh, I see it was solved, maybe it might help anybody else. Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem with the wired connection was a loose cable.  However, the problem of wireless not working remains, even though wireless works on this machine for later versions of Kubuntu.  It also works on my other laptop running Kubuntu 14.04.5.